# Class template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

How can I achieve something like so:

```
AllocFactorPolicy<1.25> allocDouble;
AllocFactorPolicy<125,-2> allocMaE;
```

I've tried something like this:

```
template<class T&>
struct AllocFactorPolicy;

template<double&& value>
struct AllocFactorPolicy
{
    double value_;
    AllocFactorPolicy(): value_(value)
    {
        cout << "double&&\n";
    }
};

template<int Mantiss, int Exponent>
struct AllocFactorPolicy
{
    int mantiss_,
        exponent_;
    AllocFactorPolicy():mantiss_(Mantiss),exponent_(Exponent)
    {
        cout << "M&E\n";
    }
};
```

but it doesn't work for me. (VS 2010 Ultimate)

Comment: I don't believe that `double&& value` makes any sense.

Comment: @Johannes here is the prove for you that it makes sense: Having double&& I can do: MyMap</*something here*/,AllocFactorPolicy<1.25>> m; Does it make sense to you now? Do you see how elegantly I can change, reapply and update any policy while defining a variable? Without this it would have to be much clamsier and not that elegant. Unless you have another idea then I'm more than happy to see it

Comment: @Johannes: Don't bother, he's much too stupid and heinous to be worth helping (see his comments on my answer, it's a model of how to get help).

Comment: @Matt, yes when I read his comment, I decided I would just ignore him.

Comment: @Matthieu I don't recall that I was in any way insulting you so why did you call me stupid even though that it was me who proved you wrong not the other way around? Frogeater.

Comment: @Johannes could you please tell me what was inapropriate in my comment to matthieu? Was I in any way insulting to him? No. Just because I've pointed out to him that it was he who made a mistake it doesn't mean that it is me who is the bad guy here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple: you declared the same class twice with different template parameters arity. That is not allowed.

Also, you can only use integral types, pointers or references as parameters "values", therefore `float` is ruled out.

You get the template idea wrong though... you don't actually need to have attributes to take the values of the values used as parameters: they are constants within your class and you can of course access them directly.

Read a good book on C++, you obviously haven't understood templates.

Comment: @Mathieu no you're wrong (at least as using floating goes). You can have template<double&& value> struct Yours{ double value_; Yours():value_(value){}}; and it will work and compile (VS2010)

Comment: @There: KennyTM already commented on this, `double&&` is not a floating point value, it's a reference to a floating point value, and I did said that references were allowed. Therefore I'm right :)

Comment: @Matthieu any idea how to specialize this class though? And if you're right why did you've said that float is rulled out? Admit that you've got confused or you just didn't know that you can pass ref to float as a param ;)

Comment: @There: I'm not confused, you cannot pass a float, but you can pass a reference / pointer to a float. The two are very different types and have very different behavior. Specifically, `Template<4>` and `Template<4>` are the same, while `Template<&4>` and `Template<&4>` may not be, especially in different translation units. If you want to use references / pointers as template parameters, they need to point to global values. It is subtil... but this is C++ we are talking about. As for how to do what you want: I don't think you really need templates here, otherwise C++0x defines the `ratio` class.

Comment: @Matthieu I do believe that you didn't know that you can pass float&&. What makes me to think so? Because you saw my code in my question and yet you have said: "Also, you can only use integral types, pointers or references as parameters "values", therefore float is ruled out." - Well it is not rulled out if you use && but you just didn't know about it and what's even more important

Comment: you do not have balls to admit that. You're also saing: "You get the template idea wrong though... you don't actually need to have attributes to take the values of the values used as parameters: they are constants within your class and you can of course access them directly " - again you just wrong. I can do it, it is allowed and it is useful in certain scenarios (just like in mine). Maybe I am not an expert in templates but I have pretty good idea what I'm talking about and it is rather you who needs good book to reeducate yourself. Did you ever hear about template specialization?

Comment: That's what is needed here. And just to prove you that it is you who doesn't know what is talking about you can compile my original code (you just have to comment all structs except one) and it works.

Comment: @Mattieu also in one of your comments you're saying:" Specifically, Template<4> and Template<4> are the same, while Template<&4> and Template<&4>" specifically you are wrong again. Template<&4> is illegal and it won't compile. My advice for you: get yourself good book and reeducate yourself.

Comment: @There: I didn't try to compile the `Template<&4>` so it might indeed be wrong, you may indeed need to refer to an existing global variable to extract a pointer/reference. And with that, I'll leave you with your problems, and do wish I could blacklist you.

Comment: @Matthieu And why would you want to blacklist me? Did I say something which was untrue? Nobody likes to get critisized but if you're making mistakes you must be prepare that someone will critisize you at some point. In this case you were wrong and I just pointed this out to you but you're to small of a man to understand it.

Comment: @Matthieu and as a matter of fact it was you who was rude to me in tone of your answer to my question: "You get the template idea wrong though" and "Read a good book on C++, you obviously haven't understood templates.
" are the sentences that I have objections to.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the whole [C++ templating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28programming%29) all wrong. Templating allows you to write a function/class once with generic types and allow any types when function/class is used.

You can't pass value data on as template parameter.

Here is an example on how you could template your `AllocFactoryPolicy`:

```
template<typename T>
struct AllocFactorPolicy
{
    T value_;
    AllocFactorPolicy(T value): value_(value)
    {

    }
    //Have getters here....
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct AllocFactorPolicy
{
    T mantiss_,
    U exponent_;
    AllocFactorPolicy(T mantiss, U exponent):mantiss_(mantiss),exponent_(exponent)
    {

    }
};
```

Then you could do

```
AllocFactorPolicy<double> allocDouble(1.25);
AllocFactorPolicy<int, double> allocMaE(125,-2);
```

**PS** It is untested, but you get the picture.

---

**Update** I see that there are 2 structs with same struct name, why don't you do something like this?

```
template<typename T>
struct AllocFactorPolicy
{
    T value_;
    T mantiss_,
    int exponent_;

    AllocFactorPolicy(T value): value_(value)
    {

    }

    AllocFactorPolicy(T mantiss, int exponent):mantiss_(mantiss),exponent_(exponent)
    {

    }
    //Have getters here....
};
```

Comment: You **can** pass value data for C++ templates, but only integral types and pointers/references are supported.

Comment: @TEG: you can pass integers as template parameters, you cannot however use floating point. The issue is elsewhere though.

Comment: @KennyTM & Matthieu you can also pass floating point if you use && i.e. template<double&&> ... it will work

Comment: @KennyTM, can C++ allow `AllocFactorPolicy<1.25> allocDouble;` and compile? If so, I will re-update this post.

Comment: @There: `double&&` is a (rvalue) reference.

Comment: @Kenny and what's the problem with this?

Comment: @There: I just mean that your comment doesn't contradict mine.

Comment: @Kenny ok so how can I specialize AllocFactorFactory that it would choose the right ver. depends on variable definition? (that's the whole point of this Q anyway)

Comment: Wait, I see that there's 2 `AllocFactoryPolicy` one with single template, and the other with 2 template methods....updating....

Comment: @The Elite.. I do not won't to do as you've proposed for the reason that I want to be able to do something like this:  Map<AllocFactorPolicy<1.25>> md; or Map<AllocFactorPolicy<102,-2>> me; and with your method it just won't work

Comment: @The Elite and why are you saying that I've got the idea wrong? My example will compile (both of the classes) if I one comment out one and next time I comment out the other? So what's your point?

Comment: @There, so can this be allowed `AllocFactorPolicy<1.25> allocDouble;`? If so, I'll re-update my post.

Comment: @The Elite yes that is allowed. Try to update your post in a way that will show me how to specialize this class.

Comment: @There, then I have no clue what you're asking/trying to do....Please kindly ignore my answer.